# Detect linebreak in sqlite3 in jinja

Tags: python, sqlite, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite db where I upload the contents through a html textarea form input. 
The contents would be displayed on a html webpage. How do I allow the webpage to read the linebreaks(enter key pressed) in the sqlite db data?

Comment: Are you saving your text as html?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ entry.description.replace('\n','<br />')|safe }}
```

replace the linebreak in sqlite, `\n` with the html linebreak, `<br/>` and using the `|safe` filter to prevent auto-escaping alowing the html linebreak to work.